# Novation Launchpad MK2 lights don't turn off from previous scenes, or freeze at certain scenes

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, equipment, fl-studio

I recently purchased a Novation Launchpad MK2 to use via FL Studio 12.

I learned that the left arrow button (third round button up top) cycles through "scenes." However, arriving at the tempo control scene, which looks like this,

[image]

immediately freezes the Launchpad. Not a single button responds (confirmed by there being no MIDI activity on FL Studio's MIDI activity view), and I have to unplug and replug the Launchpad.

Avoiding that scene though, if I cycle through enough scenes, eventually there will come a time when the Launchpad seems to fail to "clear" the lights from the previous scene, leaving a mix of lights between the current scene (or the clips view) and the previous scene.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting and self-answering because my Google searches only led me to specific Ableton channel issues (I'm using FL Studio), lightshow issues (I'm not concerned with the lightshow feature), or users who can't get any lights to light at all (my lights were mostly fine). The answer is kind of obvious but I hope it helps someone:

**Update the Launchpad's firmware *and* USB driver.** Here's [Novation's Downloads page for the Launchpad](http://global.novationmusic.com/support/product-downloads?product=Launchpad). If the link dies, you can search "Novation Launchpad Downloads."

I think what might be happening is that Windows Update provides a more recent version of the USB driver than your Launchpad shipped with. So when your Launchpad, with its older firmware, tries to "speak" to your computer in a newer "language," things get lost in translation. Once you update your firmware and USB driver together, everything will be speaking the same language. This fixed both issues for me.